# Are SciPy Kernel Density values dependent upon the density per unit area or volume when using 2D or 3D poiint data?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, kernel-density

I am using `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` in Python to estimate the probability density function of a large 3D point cloud.The data are in a metric coordinate system.  I have generated the Kernel Density estimates for the points.

Visually, the KDE values are what I expect when I plot the data  in 3D: higher values are found around point clusters, etc.  But, I am struggling to understand how to interpret the KDE values themselves.  Are KDE values dependent upon the density per unit area or volume when using 2D or 3D data, respectively?